# How many subproblems are there in this Activity Selection recursive breakdown?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, greedy

[Activity Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem): Given a set of activities A with start and end times, find a maximum subset of mutually compatible activities.

---

**My problem**

The two approaches seem to be the same, but the numSubproblems in firstApproach is exponential, while in  secondApproach is `O(n^2)`. If I were to memoize the result, then how can I memoize firstApproach?

---

**The naive firstApproach**

```
let max = 0
for (a: Activities):
    let B = {Activities - allIncompatbleWith(a)}
    let maxOfSubproblem = ActivitySelection(B)
    max = max (max, maxOfSubproblem+1)
return max


1. Assume a particular activity `a` is part of the optimal solution
2. Find the set of activities incompatible with `a: allIncompatibleWith(a)`.
2. Solve Activity for the set of activities: ` {Activities - allImcompatibleWith(a)}`
3. Loop over all activities  `a in Activities` and choose maximum.
```

---

**The CLRS Section 16.1 based secondApproach**

```
Solve for S(0, n+1)

let S(i,j) = 0
for (k: 0 to n):
    let a = Activities(k)
    let S(i,k) = solution for the set of activities that start after activity-i finishes and end before activity-k starts
   let S(k,j) = solution for the set of activities that start after activity-k finishes and end before activyty-j starts.
    S(i,j) = max (S(i,k) + S(k,j) + 1)
return S(i,j)


1. Assume a particular activity `a` is part of optimal solution
2. Solve the subproblems for: 
(1) activities that finish before `a` starts 
(2) activities that start after `a` finishes.

Let S(i, j) refer to the activities that lie between activities i and j (start after i and end before j). 
Then S(i,j) characterises the subproblems needed to be solved above. ),
S(i,j) = max S(i,k) + S(k,j) + 1, with the variable k looped over j-i indices.
```

**My analysis**

firstApproach:

`#numSubproblems  = #numSubset of the set of all activities = 2^n.`

secondApproach:

`#numSubproblems = #number of ways to chooose two indicises from n indices, with repetition. = n*n = O(n^2)`

The two approaches seem to be the same, but the numSubproblems in firstApproach is exponential, while in  secondApproach is `O(n^2)`. What's the catch? Why are they different, even thought the two approaches seem to be the same?

Comment: The second approach is not `O(n^2)`. It is also exponential without memoization. In fact, it's time complexity is O(n^3) with memoization. The number of states of the dynamic programming solution is `n^2` whereas it is `2^n` in case of the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The two approaches seem to be the same

The two solutions are not the same. The difference is in the number of states possible in the search space. Both solutions exhibit overlapping sub-problems and optimal substructure. Without memoization, both solutions browse through the entire search space.

### Solution 1

This a [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) solution where all subsets that are compatible with an activity are tried and each time an activity is selected, your candidate solution is incremented by 1 and compared with the currently stored maximum. It utilizes no insight of the start times and end times of the activities. The major difference is that the **state** of your recurrence is the entire subset of activities (compatible activities) for which the solution needs to be determined (regardless of their start and finish times). If you were to memoize the solution, you would have to use a bitmasks (or (`std::bitset` in C++) to store the solution for a subset of activities. You could also use `std::set` or other `Set` data structures.

### Solution 2

The number of **states** for the sub-problems in the second solution are greatly reduced because the recurrence relation solves for only those activities which finish before the start of the current activity and those activities which start after the current activity finishes. Notice that the number of **states** in such a solution is determined by the number of possible values of the tuple (start time, end time). Since, there are **n** activities, the number of **states** are atmost **n<sup>2</sup>**. If we memoize this solution, we simply need to store the solution for a given start time and end time, which automatically gives a solution for the subset of activities that fall in this range, regardless of whether they are compatible among themselves.

Comment: I believe the first approach does utilize the notion of {startTime, endTime), since allIncompatibleWith(a) would only return the activities which end before startTime and start after endTime. Specifically, allIncompatibleWith(a_k) returns the union of S(i,k) and S(k,j). Let's leave aside memoization for a bit.  Without memoization, both approach can seen as a backtracking approach. The second approach just splits each node of the first approach in two.

Comment: `allIncompatibleWith(a_k)` does not return the union of `S(i,k)` and `S(k,j)`. `S(i,k)` returns the solution (maximum number of activities possible) for a subset of activities in `allIncompatibleWith(a_k)`. The sub-problems constructed in the first solution are not the same. You could simply code the solution to see that. Of course, without memoization, both the solutions are exponential.

Comment: Both solutions are exponential. Just trying to understand the mathematics here. Your analysis is mistaken: the solution to allIncompatibleWith(a_k) does return the union to the solutions of S(i,k) and S(k,j). I've written the code and proved it mathematically.

Comment: I understand the discrepancy myself now. The subproblems are not the same only in "name". The first approach has 2^n different names, while the second one has O(n^2) different names. The key insight is this: if A = B union C, and B varies over n values, and C varies m values, then we have mn unique values of A, but only m + n unique values of B and C. So, in this instance, A is the "name" of the subproblem in the first approach, and B and C are the names of the subproblems in the second approach. While A ends up having 2^n unique names, there are only O(n^2) unique names for B and C.

Comment: Without memoization, both approaches do the *exact* same computations.

Comment: Sorry, I meant  the solution to (A -  allIncompatibleWith(a_k) ) is the union to the solution of S(i,k) and S(k,j). If we represent the former by a node in the recursion tree, the latter just splits the node in two. The number of function calls in the latter is actually more than the former, so I think the second approach might be slower than the former (without memoization, I mean)

Comment: Yes, what you call as names are popularly known as dynamic programming state space. Yes, without memoization it will do the exact same computations. S(i,j) returns the solution, it does not return any subsets and we do not need the subsets for the solution.
And yes, as you've pointed out in the previous comment, the solution to `(A - allIncompatibleWith(a_k) )` is the solution to union of S(i,k) and S(k,j) where `k` is casually represented to denote start and end times of activity-k.

Comment: So do you agree that it would be correct to say that the two solutions, as given in the pseudocode, are the same? Only if I add memoizaton with the names/state characterization suggested by arguments to the recursive call would they diverge in their time and space complexity (with the former remaining exponential and the latter reducing to O(n^3) time and O(n^2) space complexity.

Comment: No, I wouldn't make that generalized statement. The optimal substructure properties in the two solutions are different. Agreed, you could apply optimal substructure to the first problem as well (on the sets), but the sub-problems differ greatly in states. If I had to state, I'll say, yes, without memory, both solutions will go on to evaluate all possible compatible combinations to arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Memoization always don't lead to polynomial time asymptotic time complexity. In the first approach, you can apply memoization, but that'll not reduce the time complexity to polynomial time.

#### What is memoization?

In simple words, memoization is nothing but a recursive solution (top-down) that stores the result of computed solution to sub-problem. And if the same sub-problem is to be calculated again, you return the originally stored solution instead of recomputing it.

#### Memoization in your first recursive solution

In your case each sub-problem is finding optimal selection of activities for a subset. So **the memoization (in your case) will result in storing the optimal solution for all the subsets.**

No doubt memoization will give you performance enhancements by avoiding recomputation of solution on a subset of activities that has been "seen" before, but it can't (in this case) reduce the time complexity to polynomial time because you end up storing the sub-solutions for every subset (in worst case).

#### Where memoization gives us real benefit?

On the other hand, if you see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memoization-1d-2d-and-3d/), where memoization is applied for fibonacci series, the total number of sub-solutions that you have to store is linear with the size of the input. And thus it drops the exponential complexity to linear.

#### How can you memoize the first solution

For applying memoization in the first approach, you need to maintain the sub-solutions. The data-structure that you can use is `Map<Set<Activity>, Integer>` which will store the maximum number of compatible activities for the given `Set<Activity>`. In java `equals()` on a `java.util.Set` works properly across all the implementations, so you can use it.

Your first approach will be modified like this:

```java
// this structure memoizes the sub-solutions
Map<Set<Activity>, Integer> map; 
ActivitySelection(Set<Activity> activities) {
    if(map contains activities)
        return map.getValueFor(activities);
    let max = 0
    for (a: activities):
        let B = {Activities - allIncompatbleWith(a)}
        let maxOfSubproblem = ActivitySelection(B)
        max = max (max, maxOfSubproblem+1)
    map.put(activities, max)
    return max
}
```

**On a lighter note:**

The time complexity of the second solution (CLRS 16.1) will be `O(n^3)` instead of `O(n^2)`. You'll have to have 3 loops for `i`, `j` and `k`. The space complexity for this solution is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer my question!  I am not looking for what memoizaton is or time complexity - the CLRS already gives the answer to that. I just want to know why the number of subproblems are different in these two particular approaches, even though the approach seem to be doing the same things.

Comment: @Plato Thanks for letting me know that the solution was not concrete enough to understand. I've updated my answer.